# Customers who bought this also bought this... Help

Tags: mysql

Hi trying to figure out this, have looked in many places but because of my table structure I'm struggling. Here is my table structure:

**users** - id, login (pk)

**lessons** - id (pk), name

**users_to_lessons** - users_LOGIN (fk), lessons_ID (fk)

How can I implement a "customers who bought this also bought this..." feature?

Comment: Can you explain why customer = user ?

Comment: Im just calling it that sorry users who bought this also bought this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your question and what you need.
Anyway, assuming your user with **id = my_user_id** gets a lesson with **id = my_lesson_id** and you want to know all the lessons of other users who got my_lesson_id, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, l.name, COUNT(l.id) as rank
FROM lessons l JOIN users_to_lessons ul
ON l.id = ul.lessons_ID
WHERE l.id<>my_lesson_id AND
  ul.users_LOGIN IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT us.login FROM users us
   JOIN users_to_lessons ls ON us.login = ls.users_LOGIN
   WHERE ls.lessons_ID = my_lesson_id
      AND us.id<>my_user_id)
GROUP BY l.id
ORDER BY rank DESC, l.name
```

Comment: I have a shop and I want to show Customers who bought this product also bought these products... I tried this but it didnt return anything

Comment: @Dan: I created a db like yours, inserted some data and run query: it works... why for you returns null?

Comment: Well I run it and change the my_user_id to 10 and it doesnt return anything is this right?

Comment: @Dan: with my edited post you have also field _rank_. Be careful: you have to substitute in query **two my_lesson_id** and **one my_user_id**.

Comment: Yeah I have student which is user ID=3 and a lesson which is lesson ID=10. Put them in and the query says successful but I get nothing.

Comment: @Dan: remember that _my_user_id_ is the one who's buying and my_lesson_id_ is the lesson your user is buying. My query (it works, I tried) gives you complete list of lessons bought from other users (not the one who's buying) different from lesson which is bought tight now. And more you have the rank now :)

Comment: Yeah im still getting no results that would help me :)

Comment: If you want, export db in a SQL file and send it to me via email... I can't tell you more, sorry. With my db and my data works perfectly...

Comment: @Dan: are you sure that other students (other than id=3) bought lesson with id=10?

Comment: Yeah a user with id 6 has lesson id 10

Comment: When can I send the database to?

Comment: @Dan: marco.giacinti at gmail.com

Comment: @Dan: ok, student with id=6 bought lesson with id=10; but that student also bought some other lesson? Anyway, I wait for your SQL file...

Comment: @Dan: edited code. You're referencing user.login instead of user.id in user_lessons !!! I think it's crazy, so I referenced wrong field. This works. :)

Comment: Ah yeah, I did think it was something to do with that, I know, I didnt develop the database might ask them why. Will this show multiple suggestions? Thanks for your help this is really good!

Comment: @Dan: my query will show everything you need: lessons bought from other users who bought current lesson and rank. Now you have to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: Ha yep accepted! just tried it, works really good, Thanks for the help

Comment: does this part work? GROUP BY l.id
ORDER rank DESC, BY l.name

Comment: @Dan: editing mistake. Look now: `GROUP BY l.id ORDER BY rank DESC, l.name`

Comment: Because im using this with my shop, how is it I replace the numbers with the relevant id's with PHP?

Comment: Well to display this on my website, the user will click on the lesson and will see the list at the bottom of the page people who bought this also bought... So when the user clicks on the lesson the sql will have to insert the relevant lesson id into the above statement, how does this happen?

Comment: Can I also ask, instead of manually putting in the u.id and the l.id, Can I have it so these are replaced on depending what pages users are on, so user 1 is on lesson id 3 page. These values would then be placed in the sql? Would I just need to have <> or u.id=u.id?

Comment: Well, that query can be built dynamically according to yuor needs. So (assuming your web site is written in PHP) you can substitute two params with the ones contained in current page user is on...

Comment: Well the query is in a php and my website uses smarty templates. How would the query look above without the values in? obviously it works when i put the values in but I dont want to do that myself. Have you got an example?

Comment: ah its ok I got it! replaced the values with $_SESSION['s_login'] and $_SESSION['s_lessons_ID']

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
select 
    lessons_ID 
from 
    users_to_lessons
where 
    user_LOGIN IN
    (
        select 
            user_LOGIN 
        from 
            users_to_lessons
        where   
            lessons_ID = 1
    )
AND 
    lessons_ID <>1
;

select 
    ul2.lessons_ID
from 
    users_to_lessons ul1
inner join 
    users_to_lessons ul2
on 
    ul1.user_LOGIN = ul2.user_LOGIN
where 
    ul1.lessons_ID = 1
AND 
    ul2.lessons_ID <> 1
;
```

Comment: Using this select 
    lessons_ID 
from 
    users_to_lessons
where 
    user_LOGIN IN
    (
        select 
            user_LOGIN 
        from 
            users_to_lessons
        where   
            lessons_ID = 1
    )
AND 
    lessons_ID <>1
;
Can I count the number of duplicates and rank them?

Comment: @Paul Creasey: your queries repeat the same lesson more than once. I think IMHO that could be better using a DISTINCT. :)

Comment: @Dan and @Marco Use 'GROUP BY' and `COUNT` to remove duplicates and get a count. Then you can use `ORDER BY` to get the most popular